# ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I cannot run my app on the bluemix. I can run it well on local.

```
    2015-12-14T21:14:04.751+0800[API/0]OUTApp instance exited with guid e498196a-4159-48a6-8e79-95c73d70e14a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e498196a-4159-48a6-8e79-95c73d70e14a", "version"=>"0b284740-d9db-45b3-9e0c-0f226d37c0d6", "instance"=>"0827df95253a4c6b83042c1c2e646e36", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1450098844}
    2015-12-14T21:15:14.412+0800[DEA/34]OUTStarting app instance (index 0) with guid e498196a-4159-48a6-8e79-95c73d70e14a
    2015-12-14T21:15:26.746+0800[App/0]OUTDetected 1024 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
    2015-12-14T21:15:26.746+0800[App/0]OUTRecommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=2
    2015-12-14T21:15:27.596+0800[App/0]OUT> gzcailanzi@1.2.0 start /home/vcap/app
    2015-12-14T21:15:27.596+0800[App/0]OUT> node fpp.js
    2015-12-14T21:16:26.834+0800[DEA/34]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
    2015-12-14T21:16:26.890+0800[API/10]OUTApp instance exited with guid e498196a-4159-48a6-8e79-95c73d70e14a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e498196a-4159-48a6-8e79-95c73d70e14a", "version"=>"0b284740-d9db-45b3-9e0c-0f226d37c0d6", "instance"=>"78c0fb8f10284080b1c575ba0a336c5c", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1450098986}
    2015-12-14T21:16:26.883+0800[App/0]ERR
```

You can watch my code in http://my.oschina.net/wffger/blog/544409

I added the referred code and pushed again. It does not work.

> 12/15/15
>   10:44 AM
>   gzcailanzi
>   an instance of the app crashed: failed to accept connections within health check timeout
>   exit status: -1, CRASHED

source code: https://coding.net/u/wffger/p/crawler-cnode/git

Comment: Could it be that your node command is executing the wrong file (`fpp.js`)? I assume you meant `app.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so easy.

```
cf push --no-route AppName
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using the wrong listening port. The following example shows part of the source for the app.js file in the starter code provided by Bluemix:

```
var port = (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
```

When the application is running on Bluemix, the VCAP_APP_HOST and VCAP_APP_PORT environment variables contain the host and port values on which to listen for incoming connections. When the application is running locally, localhost is used as the host and 3000 is used as the port number. Written this way, you can run the application locally for testing purposes and on Bluemix without making further changes.

Comment: Hello Umberto Manganiello, I still don't know how to fix this problem. https://coding.net/u/wffger/p/crawler-cnode/git

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the port provided to you by the environment variables?

You should use [process.env.PORT](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#PORT) to set your application's listening port.